# Spark EC-2 deployment error: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I have a question in regard to deploying a spark application on a standalone EC-2 Cluster. I have followed the tutorial by Spark ans was able to successfully deploy a standalone EC-2 cluster. I verified that by connecting to the clusrer UI and making sure that everything is as it supposed to be. I developed a simple application and tested it locally. Everything works fine. When I submit it to the cluster (just changing --master local[4] into --masers spark://.... ) I get the following error:  ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: **Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.**  Does any one know how to overcome this problem. my deploy-mode is client.

Comment: Hi again, I have figured out what was the problem ... I got this error because TCP was not allowed in the security rules. That's why I couldn't connect to the master. One I added TCP security rules inbound and outbound. IT worked. However, in my particular situation, I faced further errors because, I used cluster mode for deployment which is not supported with standalone clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have provided the correct url to the master.

Basically, the exact spark master URL is displayed on the page when you connected to the Web UI.

URL on the page is something like: Spark Master at spark://IPAddress:port

Also you may notice that web UI and the Spark running port numbers may be different